# Custom IP sorting for Extjs grid

Tags: extjs, grid, ip

Can anyone help me in sorting IPs for one column in Extjs Grid.
Where the IP's may contain any combination of number but instead of sorting them as string I want to sort them like below.

167.254.182.001
167.254.182.6
167.254.182.8
167.254.182.9
167.254.182.10
167.254.182.10
167.254.182.11
167.254.182.121

[IP column sort](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3e6h)

Comment: Just click on the ip address column header and it will be alphabetically sorted. Or what kind of sorting do you mean?

Comment: Hi @ArthurRubens,
I want to sort the Ips to be sorted like below.

167.254.182.001

167.254.182.6
167.254.182.8
167.254.182.9
167.254.182.10
167.254.182.10
167.254.182.11
167.254.182.121

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write appropriate sortType function for model field:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Node IP test',
                store: {
                    fields: [{
                        name: 'ip',
                        sortType: function (str) {
                            let ipAddressWithLeadingZeroes = str.split('.').map(ipToken => {
                                let ipAddressWithoutLeadingZeroes = parseInt(ipToken).toString()
                                while (ipAddressWithoutLeadingZeroes.length < 3) {
                                    ipAddressWithoutLeadingZeroes = "0" + ipAddressWithoutLeadingZeroes;
                                }
                                return ipAddressWithoutLeadingZeroes;
                            }).join('.');
                            return ipAddressWithLeadingZeroes;
                        }
                    }],
                    data: [{
                        "ip": "167.254.182.10"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.8"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.121"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.11"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.001"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.10"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.6"
                    }, {
                        "ip": "167.254.182.9"
                    }, ]
                },
                columns: [{
                    text: 'IP',
                    dataIndex: 'ip',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

P.S.
Don't forget to click on column header to sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.apply(Ext.data.SortTypes, {
    asIP: (value) => value.split('.')
        .map((v) => parseInt(v).toString().padStart(3, '0'))
        .join('.')
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                title: 'Node IP test',
                multiColumnSort: true,
                store: {
                    fields: [
                        'name', 
                        {
                            name: 'ip',
                            sortType: 'asIP'
                        }
                    ],
                    data: [{
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.10"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.8"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.121"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02502",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.11"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02503",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.001"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.254.181.10"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.254.182.6"
                    }, {
                        "name": "rtxv02501",
                        "ip": "167.2.182.9"
                    }, ]
                },
                columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    text: 'IP',
                    dataIndex: 'ip',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
});
```